# Default terminal + default task

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, conemu

I have enabled the "default terminal for console applications". Now when I run "cmd", I get a ConEmu terminal. This is fine and what I want.

Furthermore, I have defined a task to launch TCC/LE instead of cmd.exe. I declared it as the startup task, so when I launch ConEmu using conemu64.exe, I get a new terminal running an instance of TCC/LE. This is fine, too.

The problem is: I cannot get the *combination* of both to work. So what I want is to run "cmd" (in the Win-R run dialog) and get both a ConEmu terminal with TCC/LE inside.  Is this possible?

Thanks for any help,
Thomas

Comment: You could write a script named `cmd.bat` that starts ConEmu with TCC/LE. That script needs to be in your `PATH` before `C:\Windows\System32`.

Comment: Note that starting something that is not cmd when starting cmd may break other applications. I would suggest you doing something else.

Comment: Only one question: Why do you want that? For example, why when you start Photoshop instead of it Word should be opened? It's your choice what to run. Run `tcc.exe` explicitly.